# Strategy for building best fit multiple regression model with time lagged variables

Tags: r, regression, time-series

I am building a multiple regression model - wrapped in a function - with one dependent variable and a dozen independent variables. The reason why I am building a function is that I need to do this analysis with approximately 75 different datasets.

The challenge is that the independent variables correlate better with the dependent variable when they are lagged in time. Unfortunately, not all time lags are the same for each variable and I would like to determine the optimal mix of time lags for each variable while getting the most optimum Adjusted R^2 value for the multiple regression model. Moreover, after building an initial model I will try to reduce the model using the `step(modelbase, direction="both")` function on the model.

In the approach I currently have I time lag all the independent variables with the same number of weeks. This results in the best possible model where all independent variables have the same time lag, but I believe (with a valid hypothesis supporting this) that there is a better model out there when we differ the time lag for each independent variable. My question is what is the best strategy to determine the best fit model without making the number of options huge. If I want to determine between 0 and 20 weeks time lag in weekly steps for 12 independent variables I am quickly up to trying to find a match between 4.096e+15 variables (=20^12).

I can imagine reducing the problem with the following strategy: Start by finding the best fit model with one independent variable at different time lags. The second step will be to add a second independent variable with its different time lags and find the best model with the two independent variables where the second is tried at different time lags while the first is kept constant. Then add a third variable for which we take a similar approach as the second by keeping the first two variables constant and change try the third with different time lags. Something tells me that this strategy might be decent approach, but something that there also might be a better overall model that contains the not optimal variables for each individual independent variable.

Is there anybody who shine some light on how to tackle this challenge?

Comment: Isn't that 20*12=240 variables (if you don't consider interactions)? 20^12 being the number of possible *models*

Comment: @Affine but you have to take the interactions in consideration.